# Performance concrens with RabbitMQ in multi-threaded environemnt

Tags: java, performance, rabbitmq

I have two simple test cases. In the first one I'm reusing both connection and channel. In the second one I'm reusing only the connection. Reason for having the second one is just to simulate channel per thread scenario in multi-threaded environment(this is not exactly same, but we can get an idea about the performance)

So from the first one I can publish 70000 msg/sec and from the second I can publish only 1500 msg/sec.

1. Does this mean channel creation is costly in RabbitMQ?
2. Can we use channel pooling to resolve this?

1st Sample

```
public class Send {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.exchangeDeclare("myExchange", "direct", true);
    channel.queueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        String message = "{\"id\" : \"56664f85-62e0-11e5-a74b-59530fbb6d8d\"" + i + "}";
        channel.basicPublish("", "myQueue", null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    channel.close();
    connection.close(); }
```

2nd Sample

```
public class Send {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare("myExchange", "direct", true);
        channel.queueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null);
        String message = "{\"id\" : \"56664f85-62e0-11e5-a74b-59530fbb6d8d\"" + i + "}";
        channel.basicPublish("", "myQueue", null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        channel.close();
    }

    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you be spawning millions of threads?

Comment: I'd guess slowness is likely do to declaring the queues and exchanges. Try removing those and see if your rate improves. You should also try to test your theory by modifying the second file such that you have three for-loops. One for making the channels and declaring the queues/exchanges, a second for publishing the messages, and a third for closing the channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple test:

```
 final int perfFor = 100000;
        d1 = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < perfFor; i++) {
            Channel channel1 = connection.createChannel();
            channel1.close();

        }
        d2 = new Date();
        seconds = (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000;
        System.out.println("Seconds-Only-CreateDestroyChannels: " + seconds);


        final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
        ExecutorService threadChannels = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
        final Date dThread = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < perfFor; i++) {

            threadChannels.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Channel channel1 = null;
                    try {
                        channel1 = connection.createChannel();
                        channel1.close();
                        if (atomicInteger.addAndGet(1) == perfFor) {
                            Date d2 = new Date();
                            long seconds = (d2.getTime() - dThread.getTime()) / 1000;
                            System.out.println("Seconds-Only-CreateDestroyChannels MultiThreads: " + seconds);
  ...
```

I got this results:

```
Seconds-Only-CreateDestroyChannels: 84
Seconds-Only-CreateDestroyChannels MultiThreads: 59
```

So, I don't think you need to create a `Channels` pool. You should have a channel for thread, it means you start you thread  and create the `Channel`.

`channel.exchangeDeclare` and `channel.queueDeclare` should be called just one time and not for each `publish`.

You also should consider to increase the `Connection` number, 1.000.000 for single `Connection` seems a bit unbalanced.

I suggest to read also [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html)   and [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html)

RabbitMQ has lot ways to improve the performance, and you should consider all your environment and not just about the `Channels` .

hope it helps